# Populate list based on data entered

Tags: php, sql, database, populate

I have a form which has a postcode field (text) and a school field (selection) and what i am trying to do is to populate the selection field with schools from a database :

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "twa312", "dam6av9a");
mysqli_select_db(twa312, $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysqli_error() );

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you worked with joins in SQL before?  You can do a select without them, but its much cleaner/faster/easier.

You'd do something like:

SELECT school_info.name AS name, local_schools.postcode AS postcode FROM school_info INNER JOIN local_schools ON local_schools.schoolID = school_info.schoolID

This will grab everything from both tables where your ID is matched.

Give that a try.  Your PHP array should end up the same.  $var['name'] and $var['postcode']

Comment: Sorry, if you set your $sql = the above query, it should work, as long as I'm understanding your database structure properly.  So:

Comment: $sql = "SELECT school_info.name AS name, local_schools.postcode AS postcode FROM school_info INNER JOIN local_schools ON local_schools.schoolID = school_info.schoolID"; instead of your 2 $sql lines up there just before the $rs = mysqli

Comment: well it seems to populate the list just fine but with every school in the database, it doesn't change based on the entered postcode.

Comment: any help with that problem?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry.  Your WHERE clause was correct:  $sql = "SELECT school_info.name AS name, local_schools.postcode AS postcode FROM school_info INNER JOIN local_schools ON local_schools.schoolID = school_info.schoolID WHERE local_schools.schoolID = " . $schoolIDvariable;

Comment: I don't remember your format for your postcode, you may have to put schoolID = '" . $var . "'"; as well.